# Apply css from another file to an echo statement from the ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a registration page (say reg.php) with a form and I am using ajax for validation of the form elements (say username).
Now, if the username already exists in the db, I want to display the error message in red and if it is available I want it to be in green.
It is working if I style the echo statement like this-

```
echo "<span style='color:brown; font-size:14px'><b>Oophs! </b>Looks like username is already in use.</span>";
```

But I want to style it from an another css file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if style it from an another css file 
>        for ex this css file is style.css   
>         write bellow line in your style.css

```
  .error_msg {   
           color:brown;    
          font-size:14px   
    }   
  .success_msg {    
          color:gree;    
          font-size:14px   
    } 

//load style.css on your html page  
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    echo "<span class='error_msg'><b>Oophs! </b>Looks like username is already in use.</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

in the page on which error will be display, inside head tag add style tag as

```
<style>
   .error {
        color:brown;
        font-size:14px;
   }
</style>
```

and echo like this

```
echo "<span class='error'><b>Oophs! </b>Looks like username is already in use.</span>";
```

Comment: escape the double quotes properly